# Expected value of number of children so that there are as many boys as girls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, expected-value

What is the expected value of $2n$ such that a couple have to make $2n$ children to have as many sons as daughters?

I calculated the probability that after $2n$ children there are as many boys as girls: it should be
$\frac{{2n}\choose{n}}{2^{2n}}.$

However, we need the probability that this is the first time that it happens, and apart from a nasty inductive formula I don't know how to deal with that...

Comment: I suppose $n=0$ doesn't count?

Comment: Well even if it counts when you calculate the expected value you multiply it by 0

Comment: Just to make sure: you're looking for the expected number of children the couple will have before the _first_ time they have equally many sons and daughters (but at least one of each), right?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant

Comment: The [Catalan Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) are close to what you want (for counting the paths to the  stop time), but you have to adapt them a bit.

Comment: You might want to look up Catalan numbers (especially the definition related to "random walks") - the number of ways to have matching numbers for the first time at $2n$ children will end up being $2 C_{n-1}$.

Comment: @lulu: A modification of the Catalan numbers will give you $P(X=k)$ for every $k$ -- but to get an _expectation_ you need the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X=k)\cdot k$ which in this case diverges. (And I don't think knowing the particular formula will make this divergence easier to see).

Comment: @HenningMakholm $100\%$ agree.  I was interested in counting the paths to a given stop time but the existence of a good count for them obviously doesn't imply that the expectation converges.  I never even thought about that side of things.  I agree with (and have upvoted) your posted solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a trick question: There is no expectation!

Without loss of generality the first child is a girl. So the expectation we're looking for is (if it exists) $1+T$ where

> $T$ is the expected number of children you need to get until the first time the number of boys is one more than the number of girls.

Let's try to compute $T$. With probability $\frac12$ the first child will be a boy, and then we're done. But otherwise -- that is again with probability $\frac12$ -- our boy deficit has just increased by one, and we need to breed $T+T$ children before we're back to zero. ($T+T$ is because expectation is additive; we can count the time it takes to make up for each missing boy separately).

But this means that
$$ T = \frac12\cdot 1 + \frac12(1+2T) $$
which is the same as
$$ T = 1 + T $$
which has no solution. So the expectation cannot exist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Very clear. But how should we interpret this? Is the expected value infinite?

Comment: By the way, shouldn't it be $2T$ instead of $(1 + 2T)$? This still leads to a contradiction...

Comment: @user404944: The $1$ in $1+2T$ is the girl who increases the boy deficit to $2$. -- saying that the expectation is "infinite" can work well for purposes of intuition, but I think it is more dignified to say: the concept of expected value does not apply to this random variable. (See also the [St. Petersburg Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox) which was one of the first analyzed examples of such a random variable).

Comment: Yes it makes sense to say that the expected value is infinite. Basically using martingale theory and stirling approximation you can compute that the probability $P(T=2n)$ decays like $ n^{-3/2}$. This means $T$ has finite pth moment iff $p<1/2$.