# Expected number of children until more girls than boys

Tags: probability, puzzle

Consider a couple that has decided to have children. They will continue having children until they have more girls than boys. What is the expected number of children they will have?

Comment: See this [near duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2938298/expected-value-of-number-of-children-so-that-there-are-as-many-boys-as-girls)

Comment: similar but different

Comment: Focus only on the odd numbered births.  That is, if, after $~2n~$ births, there are more girls than boys, then there must be at least two more girls than boys.  This is because $~2n~$ is an even number, so the number of girls and number of boys (that sum to $~2n~$) must have the same odd even parity.  So, you would then conclude that after $~2n-1~$ births there (still) must have been more girls than boys.

Comment: The same argument works in this case with minimal changes.

Comment: There are also questions like https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1986723/139123 that deal with the same problem in a more abstract way.